# Possible alternatives to vagrant-vCenter plugin?

Tags: vagrant, puppet, provisioning, vsphere

I'm currently looking for a provisioning-solution to deploy, configure and customize VMs in a vSphere / vCenter environment automatically. By doing that, I would like to adopt some changes to each VM individually (e.g. by using different licence keys for different software products).

During my research, I found that vagrant in combination with the vagrant-vcenter plugin with the help of puppet and git (by having different branches for different kinds of VMs) is doing exactly what i want to achieve:
  https://github.com/gosddc/vagrant-vcenter
Unfortunatly, this plugin is immature and still in a beta-state.

Does anyone of you know a suitable alternative (could also be commercial)?

Answer (score 2):

I searched for the same since few months. There is no other way to do that currently except using the plugin and modifying it according to your requirements. There is no other commercial solution currently in place. I used the both the plugins vagrant-vcenter and vagrant-vcloud and I was able to do the basic provisioning stuff without issues. You will not have any issues until you want to customize a lot during deployment. Some of the customization you can achieve through scripts that you can run using puppet after the VM is provisioned on vCenter.

Answer (score -1):

There are several libraries out there to interact with vCeneter. The one I use is https://github.com/rlane/rbvmomi. The code base is somewhat old, but so is vCenter. The Vagrant implementation is great for dev, but has several issues going to full blown staging or production environment. For the latter, a library to interact with the underlying API of vCenter such as rbvmomi is preferred.

Comment: You're making the wrong implication. It's not because some product is old, that it's not maintained. vCenter gets updates all the time, while the code in your reference isn't updated in 4 years